# How to prevent the usage of the same object on compile time?

Tags: c++, synchronization, pthreads, compile-time

I have wrote the small timer using pthreads. The code is rather simple

```
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

class timer 
{ 
    public: 
        timer(const std::clock_t sec): m_sec(sec) {}
        void set_time(const std::clock_t sec) 
        {
            m_sec = sec;
        }
        void start()
        { 
            _start_time = std::clock(); 
        } 
        void restart() 
        { 
            _start_time = std::clock(); 
        }
        bool tick()
        {
            for(double elpsd = elapsed(); elpsd <= m_sec; elpsd = elapsed())
            {
                if(elpsd <= m_sec) {}
            }
            return true;
        }
        double elapsed() const 
        { 
            return double(std::clock() - _start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
        } 
        double elapsed_max() const 
        { 
            return (double((std::numeric_limits<std::clock_t>::max)()) - double(_start_time)) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
        } 
        double elapsed_min() const 
        { 
            return double(1)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
        } 
    private: 
        std::clock_t _start_time; 
        std::clock_t m_sec;
}; 

class worker
{
public:
   void operator ()()
   {
       start();
   }
   virtual void start() = 0;
   virtual ~worker() = 0;
};

inline worker::~worker()
{
}

class some_worker : public worker
{
   std::string msg;
public:
   some_worker(std::string p_msg) :
       msg(p_msg)
   {
   }
   ~some_worker(){}
   void start()
   {
       std::cout << msg << std::endl;
   }
};

class timer_handler
{
   worker* work;
   pthread_t id;
   pthread_attr_t attr;
   timer* m_timer;

public:
   timer_handler(const timer* const tm, const worker* const p_work)
   {
       assert(p_work != 0);
       work = const_cast<worker*>(p_work);
       pthread_attr_init(&attr);
       assert(tm != 0);
       m_timer = const_cast<timer*>(tm);
   }

   void start()
   {
       pthread_create(&id, &attr, (void* (*)(void*))&run, this);
   }

   static void run(timer_handler *working_class)
   {
       working_class->m_timer->start();
       while(1) {
           if(working_class->m_timer->tick()) {
               working_class->work->operator()();
               working_class->m_timer->restart();
           }
       }
   }

   int join()
   {
       return pthread_join(id, NULL);
   }

   ~timer_handler()
   {
       pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
       delete work;
       delete m_timer;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   some_worker* wrk = new some_worker("Worker no: 1");
   some_worker* wrk_2 = new some_worker("Worker no: 2");
   timer* tm = new timer(1);
   timer_handler* handler = new timer_handler(tm, wrk);
   timer_handler* handler_2 = new timer_handler(tm, wrk_2);
   handler->start();
   handler_2->start();
   handler->join();
   handler_2->join();
   return 0;
}
```

But the in the main() these two handlers are use the same timer and it can be the cause of problem, because f.e. one thread can call timer->start(), another can call restart() and etc. The question is how to prevent the usage of the same object on compile time instead of using mutex which can be useful only on run-time.

Comment: make them store the timer internally, so that each has different timer. Also this is C++, spamming new keyword everywhere will only lead to trouble. In this program even, you leak 5 objects

Comment: Do you mean that timer object should be created into timer_handler class ?

Comment: yes, and dont make it pointer. as I said, in C++, new means something very different from other languages(like Java, Javascript etc)

Comment: ok, thanks for answer. But why not to use pointers ? It is more convenient for me, moreover I don't forget about memory deallocation, in timer_handler I have a destructor which is busy to delete pointers.

Comment: imagine you write `timer_handler h1(new timer(), new some_worker()); timer_handler h2 = h1;` now your code will try to delete the same pointers twice. You also dont delete anything in main, so in the end, no destructor will be called regardless

Comment: You know it is another question connected with copy constructor and assignment operator I know about this. By the way not a bad idea, i can write these functions.